# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

So my project is a reactjs web app, which stores its data in a firestore realtime database. Originally all the components were class-based but I was refactoring it all into functional components and that's when I encountered the error mentioned in the title.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined
    at Chat (Chat.js:61)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23620)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:23447)
    at react-dom.development.js:23324
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:417)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:390)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:157)
```

that error is for this line in my code:

```
Header />
  59 | </div>
  60 | <div className="user-info">
> 61 |  Logged in as: <strong id="user-tag">{state.user.displayName}</strong>
     | ^  62 | </div>
  63 | {console.log("the log: " + state.user.displayName)}
  64 | <div className="chatbox">
```

I also get this error:

```
    index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
        at Chat (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:804:83)
        at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:114703:29)
        at PrivateRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:38:14)
        at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:114905:29)
        at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:114338:30)
        at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:113958:35)
        at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:99:83)
    console.<computed> @ index.js:1
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth } from "../services/firebase";
import { db } from "../services/firebase";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import { writeChats } from "../helpers/db";

function Chat() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        user: auth().currentUser,
        chats: [],
        content: "",
        readError: null,
        writeError: null,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setState({ readError: null });
        console.log("read error set to null now attempting to fetch data");
        try {
            db.ref("messages").on("value", (snapshot) => {
                let chats = [];
                snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
                    chats.push(snap.val());
                });
                setState({ chats });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            this.setState({ readError: err.message });
        }
        console.log("data fetched");
    }, []);

    function handleChange(event) {
        setState({
            content: event.target.value,
        });
    }

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setState({ writeError: null });
        try {
            await writeChats({
                name: state.user.displayName,
                content: state.content,
                timestamp: Date.now(),
                uid: state.user.uid,
            });
            setState({ content: "" });
        } catch (error) {
            setState({ writeError: error.message });
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="chatter">
            <div className="header">
                <Header />
            </div>
            <div className="user-info">
                Logged in as: <strong id="user-tag">{state.user.displayName}</strong>
            </div>
            {console.log("the log: " + state.user.displayName)}
            <div className="chatbox">
                <div className="chats">
                    {state.chats.map((chat) => {
                        return (
                            <p key={chat.timestamp} style={{ fontSize: "1.2rem" }}>
                                {chat.content}
                                <code style={{ fontSize: "0.5rem" }}>&nbsp;{chat.name}</code>
                            </p>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
                <div className="input-group">
                    <form className="textbar" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <input
                            style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
                            size="50"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={state.content}
                        ></input>
                        {state.error ? <p>{state.writeError}</p> : null}
                        <button className="send-btn" type="submit">
                            Send
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Chat;
```

This is probably some basic mistake but I don't know what to do so, please bear with me.
My one guess is that maybe that line `state.user.displayName` refers to an older version of my state, which I created with the `useState()` hook since I read that each update in the state re-renders the whole component, so maybe I need to use context but I'm not sure, so please help me and let me know if there's any details you need for this.

Edit note: I've posted the whole code for this error, please let me know what other mistakes I'm doing here, like if I'm breaking any coding practice or any other serious mistake. Ah I know those inline css statements are bad, sorry about that.

Comment: How are you updating `state`?

Comment: with the setState() function that's returned with the state initialization

Comment: Should I post the whole code? I mean that one file

Comment: @AnandThevar Pls do

Comment: Please add relevant code where the user state is being set.

Answer (score 1):

Take note that the behaviour of class-based `setState()` is different from the functional hooks alternative (`useState`). The former one merges the object you provide with the current state. In the hooks case - the object is completely replaced without persisting anything from the current state so you're left with what you supply to the `setX` setter.

This is exactly the cause of your problem.

You're not modifying the state properly. You're replacing the whole `state` object without persisting the not-modified values. For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setState({ readError: null });
    console.log("read error set to null now attempting to fetch data");
    try {
        db.ref("messages").on("value", (snapshot) => {
            let chats = [];
            snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
                chats.push(snap.val());
            });
            setState({ chats });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        this.setState({ readError: err.message });
    }
    console.log("data fetched");
}, []);
```

And more specifically:

```
setState({ chats });
```

Here, you're replacing your

```
{
    user: auth().currentUser,
    chats: [],
    content: "",
    readError: null,
    writeError: null,
}
```

object with this:

```
{
    chats: [...]
}
```

therefore you no longer have `state.user` hence the error. You should be doing:

```
setState(state => ({ ...state, chats: chats }));
```

You should do this for all your state changes (I guess).

Also, you have class-related artifacts which you haven't cleared as `this.setState({ readError: err.message });` for example. Using `this` in a functional component is a no-no.

Start with this and modify where necessary:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth } from "../services/firebase";
import { db } from "../services/firebase";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import { writeChats } from "../helpers/db";

function Chat() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        user: auth().currentUser,
        chats: [],
        content: "",
        readError: null,
        writeError: null,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        try {
            db.ref("messages").on("value", (snapshot) => {
                let chats = [];

                snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
                    chats.push(snap.val());
                });

                setState(state => {
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        chats: chats
                    };
                });
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            setState(state => {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    readError: err.message
                };
            });
        }

        console.log("data fetched");
    }, []);

    function handleChange(event) {
        setState(state => {
            return {
                ...state,
                content: event.target.value
            };
        });
    }

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        setState(state => {
            return {
                ...state,
                writeError: null
            };
        });

        try {
            await writeChats({
                name: state.user.displayName,
                content: state.content,
                timestamp: Date.now(),
                uid: state.user.uid,
            });

            setState(state => {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    content: ""
                };
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            setState(state => {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    writeError: error.message
                };
            });
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="chatter">
            <div className="header">
                <Header />
            </div>
            <div className="user-info">
                Logged in as: <strong id="user-tag">{state.user.displayName}</strong>
            </div>
            {console.log("the log: " + state.user.displayName)}
            <div className="chatbox">
                <div className="chats">
                    {state.chats.map((chat) => {
                        return (
                            <p key={chat.timestamp} style={{ fontSize: "1.2rem" }}>
                                {chat.content}
                                <code style={{ fontSize: "0.5rem" }}>&nbsp;{chat.name}</code>
                            </p>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
                <div className="input-group">
                    <form className="textbar" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <input
                            style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
                            size="50"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={state.content}
                        ></input>
                        {state.error ? <p>{state.writeError}</p> : null}
                        <button className="send-btn" type="submit">
                            Send
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Chat;
```

Also, I advice you to separate your `state` into different variables (different `useState` calls) as some of them seem unrelated and just harm maintainability and clarity.

Comment: I tried what you said but now I get a syntaxError for unexpected token
`code`
/src/pages/Chat.js
SyntaxError: E:\Projects\re-blotin\src\pages\Chat.js: Unexpected token (25:26)
`
  23 |      chats.push(snap.val());
  24 |     });
> 25 |     setState((state) => { ...state, state.chats: chats, });
     |                           ^
  26 |    });
  27 |   } catch (err) {
  28 |    setState({ readError: err.message });

how do you format this?

Comment: It should be `setState(state => ({ ...state, chats: chats }));`.

Comment: Other issues: `state.error ? <p>{state.writeError}</p> : null` should check `state.writeError`, assumes user has read permissions for everything under `/messages`, assumes user is logged in, user logging out isn't handled, database listener is not properly unsubscribed, `try`/`catch` around the database call isn't actually doing anything (instead an `onCancel` handler is passed as the second argument to [`ref.on()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#optional-cancelcallbackorcontext:-a:-error-=-any-|-object-|-null))

Comment: Okay I tried that and it went back to the same error that I mentioned in the question

Comment: @AnandThevar Well, that means you have even more problems in your code. It is poorly written and it is hard to understand it properly. Debug your code and see what's the value of `user` in `state` when you assign it on component creation. I suppose it is `undefined` from the very beginning. In short, check what `auth().currentUser` returns.